# Can regular expression match this pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match `[#ABABAB]blah blah blah[/#ABABAB]`

but I don't want to match `[#ABABAB]blah blah blah[/#000000]`

the ABABAB and 000000 are hex color code.

The first one is what I want as its color code of open tag and close tag are the same, but the second one is not.

I have tried this pattern but it did not work: `\[#[0-9|A-F]{6}\].*\[/#[0-9|A-F]{6}\]`

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("[#ABABAB]blah blah blah[/#ABABAB]"));` will match the first string but not the second... More seriously: you should explain what you have tried and why it does not work, and clarify *why* the first input is ok but not the second.

Comment: Are you writing it for a single color code? Or an arbitrary color code, to be extracted as part of RE matching?

Comment: @Arkadiy arbitrary one. Yes, I want the close tag must equals to the open tag

Comment: Then capture the hex code and use that in the second place

Comment: @assylias ` \\[#[0-9|A-F]{6}\\].*\\[/#[0-9|A-F]{6}\\ ` I tried something like this, It match the open tag and close tag, but I don't know how to write a regex that requires the color code of open tag and close tag are the same.

Comment: Is it possible that your data can look like `[#aaaaaa]xxxx[#bbbbbb]yyyy[/#bbbbbb]xxxxx[/#aaaaaa]`? If that is true then what should be the matching part?

Comment: @Pshemo Yup, Absolutely. I am thinking about that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your input can look like

```
"xxxx[#aaaaaa]yyyyy[#bbbbbb]zzzzzz[/#bbbbbb]yyyyy[/#aaaaaa]zzzzzz"
```

where `x` will have default color, `y` will have aaaaaa color, and `z` will have bbbbbb color, and you want to find

```
[#aaaaaa]yyyyy[#bbbbbb]zzzzzz[/#bbbbbb]yyyyy[/#aaaaaa]
```

and

```
[#bbbbbb]zzzzzz[/#bbbbbb]
```

you should add [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (?=...) mechanism to [arshajii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127670/1393766) making your regex

```
"(?=(\\[(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\\].*?\\[/\\2\\]))"
```

---

demo

```
String data="xxxx[#aaaaaa]yyyyy[#bbbbbb]zzzzzz[/#bbbbbb]yyyyy[/#aaaaaa]zzzzzz";

Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?=(\\[(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\\].*?\\[/\\2\\]))");
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

output

```
[#aaaaaa]xxxx[#bbbbbb]yyyy[/#bbbbbb]xxxxx[/#aaaaaa]
[#bbbbbb]yyyy[/#bbbbbb]
```

Comment: Why m.matches() return false?

Comment: @benleung Because the regex doesn't match the text exactly, it's meant to extract pieces of it.

Comment: @arshajii Thanks for clearing it out, something came up so couldn't do it myself.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
\[(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\].*?\[/\1\]
```

---

```
System.out.println("[#ABABAB]blah blah blah[/#ABABAB]"
        .matches("\\[(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\\].*?\\[/\\1\\]"));

System.out.println("[#ABABAB]blah blah blah[/#000000]"
        .matches("\\[(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\\].*?\\[/\\1\\]"));
```

```
true
false
```

Comment: hex color code : valid characters are 0-9 and A-F and a-f and we also know it will be exactly 6 characters